# Android Layout Positioning

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout where I have a image and to the right of the image the users name, then also to the right but below the name the users date of birth and then users location below that. Though not to sure how to position the items properly. In my code below you can see that I have tried to combine the layout_below and layout_toRightOf. With the first text view by itself it positions the name correctly but when I add the other two they all end up in the the top right corner.

Am I correct to believe that using toRightOf followed by below cancels out the first layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_white"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/unset"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_image" >
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/dob" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/unset"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_image"
            android:layout_below="@id/name">
   </TextView>
   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/location" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/unset"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_image"
            android:layout_below="@id/dob">
   </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use something like this psuedocode

```
<scrollview>
    <linearlayout> vertical
        <Linearlayout> horizontal
            <imageview>
            <linearlayout> vertical
                <textview>
                <textview>
                <textview>
            </linearlayout>
        </linearlayout>
    </linearlayout>
</scrollview>
```

Comment: Thanks used this with the example from the android site and have it working now the way I like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo your imageView id is @+id/profile_image and on the rest of the layout you are referencing to "@id/icon_image".
Try with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/profile_image"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_white"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="150dp" 
          android:contentDescription="@string/image_description">
      </ImageView>
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/name" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/unset"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image" >
     </TextView>
     <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/dob" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/unset"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
              android:layout_below="@id/name">
     </TextView>
     <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/location" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/unset"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
              android:layout_below="@id/dob">
     </TextView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```